# PHP - Function name from variable

Tags: php, function, variables

Okay, I've found a possible solution for this, but for some reason, I can't make it work in my application. Apparently, if I have a variable which contains a name function, I could use

```
<?php echo $variable(); ?>
```

to output the function with the same name.

I'm using Codeigniter. It has a function in its Form helper to output a text field, which is

```
<?php form_input(); ?>
```

I have a variable

```
<?php $instance['taxon_field'] = 'form_input'; ?>
```

If I echo out this variable, I do get the needed value, 'form_input'. However, as soon as I try to echo

```
$instance['taxon_field']()
```

I get a warning:

```
Message: Illegal string offset 'taxon_field'
```

and a fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function p()
```

I am really clueless here, because echoing only the variable gives 'form_input', but echoing $variable() only gives 'p'.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I created a sample PHP file with `function form_field(){echo 'yay';} $instance=array('taxon_field'=>'form_field'); $instance['taxon_field']();` .. and it worked perfectly fine. Sounds like `$instance` is a string, not an array (in your case)

Comment: Pretty sure this was a php 5.3 addition.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback newfurniturey, at least I'm glad I'm not going crazy :) But I've been banging my head about this for an hour, and am still not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: wes I'm running PHP Version 5.4.4

Comment: To give some more clarification. If I put $name = $instance['taxon_field'] and then echo $name, I get the right $name value. But if I echo $name(), suddenly my $instance array's value is converted to the value of $instance['taxon_value'], which is the last array member of $instance.

Comment: I've made a longer description on this forum: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/224312/ if you have some time, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem here is that `$instance` is not an array, but a string. Judging from the error message, it's a string whose value starts with `p`.

The syntax `$var[$key]` is used not only to access array elements but also to index into strings, where `$var[0]` would be the first character (actually, byte) of `$var` etc. If `$instance` is a string and you write `$instance['taxon_field']` then PHP will try to convert `'taxon_field'` to an integer in order to index into the string. This results in `0` as per the usual [conversion rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), so the whole expression gets you the first letter of the string.

Assuming that the string starts with `p` it's then pretty obvious why it tries to call a function with that name.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that he get the "Call to undefined function p()" error mean that it actually does work to call a function in that way?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that too. Unfortunately, it's giving the same warning and the same error.

Comment: MrAzulay I'm not sure. If it is so, how (and why) does it change the function name from 'form_input' (or anything else that's stored in the given variable, for that matter) to only 'p'?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ: Please see the updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: @Jon you're right. It does make sense to me now. But why (oh why?!) am I still not able to get what I want even if I store the array's value in a single variable? Especially because $var = 'form_input' does work as expected, but $var = $instance['taxon_field'] doesnt?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ: `var_dump($instance)` will help.

Comment: @Jon $instance is not a string, it's an array. var_dump($instance) gives an array(30) result. There are a few of its members that start with a 'p', but I'm guessing that it's the last one that is causing this: ["type"]=>string(4) "page". As I said before, if I print_r($instance) or if I echo any of its members, everything works fine. But if I add $instance['taxon_field']() below (either turning it into a variable or not), I get the error. I can't figure out how can an error be throwon retro-actively like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
call_user_func($instance['taxon_field']);
```

Comment: I am aware that your answer should work. But it's not working in my application for a reason I can't seem to find out, and that's confusing me.

Comment: I think we need to see the complete script

Comment: Also works for me: http://codepad.org/7CZMGUEG  . codepad.org is running PHP5.2 , I had tested it local with PHP 5.4.4 , same result.

Comment: Okay, I think I have a clue about why this isn't working, but still don't know how to override it. I'll post more info in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion created is actually my own fault because I failed to provide some aditional information which I thought was not important, but turned out to be crutial. My $instance[] array is actually a result of a foreach loop (two of them, to be precise) and is a part of a bigger multidimensional array. The actual code is more complicated, but I'll try to represent it right:

```
<?php
$bigger_array = array(
    0 => array(
        'field_one' => 'value_one',
        'field_two' => 'value_two',
        'field_three' => 'new_function'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'field_one' => 'new_value_one',
        'field_two' => 'new_value_two',
        'field_three' => 'echo'
    )
);

function new_function()
{
    echo 'New function called.';
}

foreach($bigger_array as $instance)
{
    $name = $instance['field_three'];
    $name('Hello World!');
}
?>
```

This will output the following:

> New function called.
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined function echo() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bla.php on line 69

In other words, the newly defined function works fine, but the built-in 'echo' doesn't.

This is actually not my original problem, this is something that I've encountered while trying to debug the initial issue. And the original problem is that creating a function from a single-dimensional array works okay. whereas creating a function from a multi-dimensional array within a foreach loop transforms the array into a string with the value of its last member.

Now, I'm still not really able to fully answer my question, but I think information I'm giving could lead to a solution. In the simplified example that I gave here, why am I getting the message that echo() function is not defined, while the new function works fine?

Comment: You receive the error, because echo is no function(the manual calls it "language construct"). Try e.g. "var_dump", and you'll see, that it works with "real" built-in functions.

Comment: Now that we are working with an multidimensional array: are you sure that all items of $bigger_array are arrays? What returns `var_dump($content['id'])` (related to your post at the codeigniter-forum)

Comment: Oh wow, you're right about "echo". Stupid me. Thanks for clarifying that, it actually makes sense. `var_dump($content['id']` gives this: http://www.pastebucket.com/2918

Comment: I also get the expected result with `$content['id']` : http://codepad.org/n7RZR2X7 (also tested in PHP 5.4.4 again) . Did you also get this result when you run this on your server?

Comment: The thing is, I do get that result with an array which I define in the same view file. Unfortunately, as I said, it is a Codeigniter project, and I need to achieve the same with an array passed from a controller to the view. And if I try to do the same thing with two identical arrays (one passed from the controller, and the other defined in the view file), I get the mentioned errors for the former and the expected result for the latter. This is beginning to frustrate me.

Comment: To be more precise, my $content["id"] is passed from the controller to the view. Then, if I try to use the loop from your http://codepad.org/n7RZR2X7 I will get the warning, the wrong variable value and the error. And if I simply copy the array's definition frmo http://codepad.org/n7RZR2X7 and paste it in the view file before the loop, it all works perfectly well. I should emphasize that the array from the controller and from the view are identical (the view array is a copy/paste of the controller array).